# Condition of an operator that makes a bilinear map an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an inner product space and $T \in \mathcal L(V)$. Under which conditions on $T$,
$V \times V \to \mathbb{F} : (u, v) \mapsto \langle Tu,v\rangle$ is an inner product on V ?

Is the purpose of this question is to limit $T$ to the definition of the inner product $\langle Tu,v\rangle$?

Comment: By definition this is true iff T$ is self adjoint and  (strictly) positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to stablish conditions on $T$ to ensure that $g(u,v) := \langle Tu,v \rangle$ is a inner product, that is, to ensure that $g$ is linear in the first entry, conjugate-linear in the second, the conjugate symmetry and the positive-definiteness.

I will help you with one of them: since we need to ensure that $g(u,v) = \overline{g(v,u)}$, we need that 
$$\langle Tu,v \rangle \stackrel{\downarrow}{=} \overline{\langle Tv,u \rangle} = \overline{\langle v,T^*u \rangle} = \langle T^*u,v \rangle,$$
in other words, we need that $T^* = T$.